# Scss ternary if on a @return directive bad result

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have the following function:

```
@function breakpoint-infix($bp) {
  @return if ($bp != 'lg', '--#{$bp}', '');
```

Then I used the function in a map:

```
.dp {
  @each $bp in map-keys($grid-config) {
      $infix: breakpoint-infix($bp);
      &-none#{$infix} {
        display: none !important;
      }} }
```

but I don't get the expected result. I get:

```
.u-dp-noneif false, .u-dp --lg {
  display: none !important; }
```

The infix, actually should remove 'lg'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space after `if`: `if ($`. Here `if` is just a function call.

An example of the `if` function possible realization:

**Sass:**

```
@function user-if($condition, $true-statement, $false-statement) {
  $output: $false-statement;

  @if ($condition) {
    $output: $true-statement;
  }

  @return $output;
}

a {
  color: user-if(true, green, red);
  z-index: user-if(false, 1, 2);
}
```

**Css:**

```
a {
  color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d9c32a830fa0b39728de2c9c339d0ffa).